# Json not parsing correctly from jQuery AJAX call in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing back Json via a jQuery AJAX call to a MVC function that takes a `Folder`.  MVC correctly parses some of the data but not the list I sent back.

**MVC**

```
public class Folder : IValidate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SearchCriteria> SearchCriteria { get; set; }
}

public class SearchCriteria
{
    public int FolderId { get; set; }
    public int SettingsEntryID { get; set; }
    public string SearchParameter { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult EditFolder(Folder folder)
{
   service.EditFolder(folder);
   return this.Json(Json(new { Success = true }));
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var folder = {
    Id: $("#groupID").val(),
    Name: $("#groupName").val(),
    SearchCriteria: []
};

$(".searchCriteria").each(function () {
    folder.SearchCriteria.push(
        {
            FolderId: $("#groupID").val(),
            SearchParameter: $(this).val(),
            SettingsEntryID: $(this).attr("id").replace("searchCriteria", "")
        });
});

$.ajax({
    url: "/settings/editfolder/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: folder,
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("wsaved");
    }
});
```

`folder`, in this function gets set with `Id` and `Name` but `SearchCriteria` is not set properly.  It is set to `null`.  If I comment out the `traditional: true` the list gets created but all the values for each `SearchCriteria` are `0` or `null`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You are *not* sending JSON. You passing an object as `data:` option, and jQuery will convert the object to a query string, like `Id=foo&Name=bar&...`. If you really want to send JSON, you have to convert the object to JSON, like `data: JSON.stringify(JSON)`. Whether that is the problem or not, I cannot say (I don't know MVC).

Comment: You are missing two points 1. `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` 2. `data: JSON.stringify(folder),` **And one correction.** URL should be like `url : "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" })"`

Comment: When you send your post, Ajax will actually send something like `SearchCriteria=Array` instead of the actual array. I didn't make binding of list by the past, but you can check this out : http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: Perfecto, please post as an answer @PKKG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two points

```
1. contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 

2. data: JSON.stringify(folder)
```

**And one correction**.

URL should be like

```
url : "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" })"
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area" })",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(folder),
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("wsaved");
    }
});
```